# Maven-code-formatter plugin ignoring my java files

Tags: eclipse, maven, maven-plugin

I have the following config in Maven but it just keeps ignoring my source files. The debug log says the Eclipse Code Formatter cold be null because of the compliance levels. I checked and all levels are 1.8 everywhere. Full log below...

output:

```
[INFO] --- maven-java-formatter-plugin:0.4:format (format) @ AIM ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to format source files.
[INFO] Number of files to be formatted: 67
[INFO] Successfully formatted: 0 file(s)
[INFO] Fail to format        : 0 file(s)
[INFO] Skipped               : 67 file(s)
[INFO] Approximate time taken: 0s
[INFO] 


    <plugin>
  <groupId>com.googlecode.maven-java-formatter-plugin</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-java-formatter-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>0.4</version>

   <executions>
          <execution>
          <id>format</id> 
          <phase>process-resources</phase> 
             <goals>
              <goal>format</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
  <configuration>
   <complianceLevel>${maven.compiler.source}</complianceLevel>
    <sourceLevel>${maven.compiler.source}</sourceLevel>
<!--     <includes> -->
<!--         <include>**/*.java</include> -->
<!--     </includes> -->
     <configFile>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/eclipse-formatter.xml</configFile>

   <compilerSource default-value="${maven.compiler.source}">${maven.compiler.source}</compilerSource>  
  <compilerTargetPlatform default-value="${maven.compiler.source}">${maven.compiler.source}</compilerTargetPlatform> 
  <compilerTarget default-value="${maven.compiler.target}">${maven.compiler.target}</compilerTarget>
   <overrideConfigCompilerVersion>false</overrideConfigCompilerVersion>  
<!--      <compilerSource>${maven.compiler.target}</compilerSource> -->
<!--     <compilerCompliance>${maven.compiler.target}</compilerCompliance> -->
<!--     <compilerTargetPlatform>${maven.compiler.target}</compilerTargetPlatform> -->
    <lineEnding>AUTO</lineEnding>
    <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
<!--     <excludes> -->
<!--       <exclude>com/relativitas/maven/plugins/formatter/special/</exclude> -->
<!--       <exclude>**/*Test.java</exclude> -->
<!--     </excludes> -->
  </configuration>
</plugin>





Apache Maven 3.2.1 (ea8b2b07643dbb1b84b6d16e1f08391b666bc1e9; 2014-02-14T11:37:52-06:00)
Maven home: /usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.2.1/libexec
Java version: 1.8.0_05, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_05.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.9.3", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[DEBUG] Reading global settings from /usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.2.1/libexec/conf/settings.xml
[DEBUG] Reading user settings from /Users/user/.m2/settings.xml
[DEBUG] Using local repository at /Users/user/.m2/repository
[DEBUG] Using manager EnhancedLocalRepositoryManager with priority 10.0 for /Users/user/.m2/repository
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[DEBUG] Extension realms for project com.domain:AIM:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: (none)
[DEBUG] Looking up lifecyle mappings for packaging war from ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]
[DEBUG] Resolving plugin prefix java-formatter from [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo]
[DEBUG] Resolved plugin prefix java-formatter to com.googlecode.maven-java-formatter-plugin:maven-java-formatter-plugin from POM com.domain:AIM:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[DEBUG] === REACTOR BUILD PLAN ================================================
[DEBUG] Project: com.domain:AIM:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[DEBUG] Tasks:   [java-formatter:format]
[DEBUG] Style:   Regular
[DEBUG] =======================================================================
[INFO] 
[INFO] Using the builder org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder with a thread count of 1
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building AIM Maven Webapp 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[DEBUG] Resolving plugin prefix java-formatter from [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo]
[DEBUG] Resolved plugin prefix java-formatter to com.googlecode.maven-java-formatter-plugin:maven-java-formatter-plugin from POM com.domain:AIM:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[DEBUG] Lifecycle default -> [validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy]
[DEBUG] Lifecycle clean -> [pre-clean, clean, post-clean]
[DEBUG] Lifecycle site -> [pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy]
[DEBUG] === PROJECT BUILD PLAN ================================================
[DEBUG] Project:       com.domain:AIM:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[DEBUG] Dependencies (collect): []
[DEBUG] Dependencies (resolve): []
[DEBUG] Repositories (dependencies): [central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2, releases), java.net2 (http://download.java.net/maven/2, releases+snapshots), com.springsource.repository.bundles.release (http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/release, releases+snapshots), com.springsource.repository.bundles.external (http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/external, releases+snapshots), spring-milestones (http://repo.spring.io/milestone, releases+snapshots)]
[DEBUG] Repositories (plugins)     : [central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2, releases)]
[DEBUG] -----------------------------------------------------------------------
[DEBUG] Goal:          com.googlecode.maven-java-formatter-plugin:maven-java-formatter-plugin:0.4:format (default-cli)
[DEBUG] Style:         Regular
[DEBUG] Configuration: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <basedir>${basedir}</basedir>
  <compilerCompliance default-value="1.5">${maven.compiler.source}</compilerCompliance>
  <compilerSource default-value="1.8">1.8</compilerSource>
  <compilerTargetPlatform default-value="1.8">1.8</compilerTargetPlatform>
  <configFile>file:///Users/user/Projects/domain/java/AIM3.0/src/main/resources/eclipse-formatter.xml</configFile>
  <encoding default-value="${project.build.sourceEncoding}">UTF-8</encoding>
  <lineEnding default-value="AUTO">AUTO</lineEnding>
  <overrideConfigCompilerVersion default-value="false">false</overrideConfigCompilerVersion>
  <sourceDirectory>${project.build.sourceDirectory}</sourceDirectory>
  <targetDirectory>${project.build.directory}</targetDirectory>
  <testSourceDirectory>${project.build.testSourceDirectory}</testSourceDirectory>
</configuration>
[DEBUG] =======================================================================
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-java-formatter-plugin:0.4:format (default-cli) @ AIM ---
[DEBUG] Created new class realm maven.api
[DEBUG] Importing foreign packages into class realm maven.api
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.cli < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.lifecycle < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.lifecycle < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.repository < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.personality < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.usability < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.configuration < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: javax.enterprise.inject.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.project < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.exception < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.spi < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.plugin < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.collection < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.logging < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.profiles < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.transfer < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.XmlPullParserException < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.execution.scope < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.rtinfo < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.impl < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.monitor < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.graph < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.metadata < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.context < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.observers < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.resource < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: javax.inject.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.model < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.Xpp3Dom < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.deployment < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.artifact < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.toolchain < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.resolution < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.XmlSerializer < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.settings < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.authorization < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.events < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.authentication < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.reporting < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.repository < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.slf4j.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.repository < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.configuration < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.classworlds < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.pull.XmlPullParser < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.classrealm < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.* < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.artifact < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.execution < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.apache.maven.wagon.proxy < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.container < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.version < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.eclipse.aether.installation < plexus.core
[DEBUG]   Imported: org.codehaus.plexus.component < plexus.core
[DEBUG] Populating class realm maven.api
[DEBUG] Dependency collection stats: {ConflictMarker.analyzeTime=1, ConflictMarker.markTime=1, ConflictMarker.nodeCount=21, ConflictIdSorter.graphTime=0, ConflictIdSorter.topsortTime=1, ConflictIdSorter.conflictIdCount=17, ConflictIdSorter.conflictIdCycleCount=0, ConflictResolver.totalTime=6, ConflictResolver.conflictItemCount=21, DefaultDependencyCollector.collectTime=81, DefaultDependencyCollector.transformTime=11}
[DEBUG] com.googlecode.maven-java-formatter-plugin:maven-java-formatter-plugin:jar:0.4:
[DEBUG]    org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:2.0:compile
[DEBUG]    org.eclipse.tycho:org.eclipse.jdt.core:jar:3.8.1.v20120125-1544:compile
[DEBUG]    org.jibx.config.3rdparty.org.eclipse:org.eclipse.text:jar:3.5.100.v20110505-0800:compile
[DEBUG]    org.jibx.config.3rdparty.org.eclipse:org.eclipse.core.runtime:jar:3.7.0.v20110110:compile
[DEBUG]    org.jibx.config.3rdparty.org.eclipse:org.eclipse.core.resources:jar:3.7.100.v20110510-0712:compile
[DEBUG]    org.jibx.config.3rdparty.org.eclipse:org.eclipse.equinox.common:jar:3.6.0.v20110523:compile
[DEBUG]    commons-digester:commons-digester:jar:2.0:compile
[DEBUG]       commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.8.0:compile
[DEBUG]       commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile
[DEBUG]    commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.4:compile
[DEBUG]    org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-io:jar:1.0.1:compile
[DEBUG]    org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-resources:jar:1.0-alpha-7:compile
[DEBUG]       org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-container-default:jar:1.0-alpha-9-stable-1:compile
[DEBUG]          junit:junit:jar:3.8.1:compile
[DEBUG]          classworlds:classworlds:jar:1.1-alpha-2:compile
[DEBUG]    org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:2.0.5:compile
[DEBUG] Created new class realm plugin>com.googlecode.maven-java-formatter-plugin:maven-java-formatter-plugin:0.4
[DEBUG] Importing foreign packages into class realm plugin>com.googlecode.maven-java-formatter-plugin:maven-java-formatter-plugin:0.4
[DEBUG]   Imported:  < maven.api
[DEBUG] Populating class realm plugin>com.googlecode.maven-java-formatter-plugin:maven-java-formatter-plugin:0.4
[DEBUG]   Included: com.googlecode.maven-java-formatter-plugin:maven-java-formatter-plugin:jar:0.4
[DEBUG]   Included: org.eclipse.tycho:org.eclipse.jdt.core:jar:3.8.1.v20120125-1544
[DEBUG]   Included: org.jibx.config.3rdparty.org.eclipse:org.eclipse.text:jar:3.5.100.v20110505-0800
[DEBUG]   Included: org.jibx.config.3rdparty.org.eclipse:org.eclipse.core.runtime:jar:3.7.0.v20110110
[DEBUG]   Included: org.jibx.config.3rdparty.org.eclipse:org.eclipse.core.resources:jar:3.7.100.v20110510-0712
[DEBUG]   Included: org.jibx.config.3rdparty.org.eclipse:org.eclipse.equinox.common:jar:3.6.0.v20110523
[DEBUG]   Included: commons-digester:commons-digester:jar:2.0
[DEBUG]   Included: commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.8.0
[DEBUG]   Included: commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1
[DEBUG]   Included: commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.4
[DEBUG]   Included: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-io:jar:1.0.1
[DEBUG]   Included: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-resources:jar:1.0-alpha-7
[DEBUG]   Included: junit:junit:jar:3.8.1
[DEBUG]   Included: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:2.0.5
[DEBUG]   Excluded: org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:2.0
[DEBUG]   Excluded: org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-container-default:jar:1.0-alpha-9-stable-1
[DEBUG]   Excluded: classworlds:classworlds:jar:1.1-alpha-2
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo com.googlecode.maven-java-formatter-plugin:maven-java-formatter-plugin:0.4:format from plugin realm ClassRealm[plugin>com.googlecode.maven-java-formatter-plugin:maven-java-formatter-plugin:0.4, parent: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@2503dbd3]
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo 'com.googlecode.maven-java-formatter-plugin:maven-java-formatter-plugin:0.4:format' with basic configurator -->
[DEBUG]   (f) basedir = /Users/user/Projects/domain/java/AIM3.0
[DEBUG]   (f) compilerCompliance = 1.8
[DEBUG]   (f) compilerSource = 1.8
[DEBUG]   (f) compilerTargetPlatform = 1.8
[DEBUG]   (f) configFile = file:///Users/user/Projects/domain/java/AIM3.0/src/main/resources/eclipse-formatter.xml
[DEBUG]   (f) encoding = UTF-8
[DEBUG]   (f) lineEnding = AUTO
[DEBUG]   (f) overrideConfigCompilerVersion = false
[DEBUG]   (f) sourceDirectory = /Users/user/Projects/domain/java/AIM3.0/src/main/java
[DEBUG]   (f) targetDirectory = /Users/user/Projects/domain/java/AIM3.0/target
[DEBUG]   (f) testSourceDirectory = /Users/user/Projects/domain/java/AIM3.0/src/test/java
[DEBUG] -- end configuration --
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to format source files.
[INFO] Number of files to be formatted: 67
[DEBUG] The resource 'file:///Users/user/Projects/domain/java/AIM3.0/src/main/resources/eclipse-formatter.xml' was not found with resourceLoader org.codehaus.plexus.resource.loader.FileResourceLoader.
[DEBUG] The resource 'file:///Users/user/Projects/domain/java/AIM3.0/src/main/resources/eclipse-formatter.xml' was found as file:/Users/user/Projects/domain/java/AIM3.0/src/main/resources/eclipse-formatter.xml.
[DEBUG] Processing file: /Users/user/Projects/domain/java/AIM3.0/src/main/java/com/domain/biz/dao/IGenericDAO.java
[DEBUG] Code cannot be formatted. Possible cause is unmatched source/target/compliance version.


[DEBUG] Code cannot be formatted. Possible cause is unmatched source/target/compliance version.
[INFO] Successfully formatted: 0 file(s)
[INFO] Fail to format        : 0 file(s)
[INFO] Skipped               : 67 file(s)
[INFO] Approximate time taken: 0s
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.539 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2014-06-28T05:34:53-06:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 9M/307M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Can you past a full error output and not excerpts of it. Furthermore i assume you've pasted `mvn -X ..` output here based on that `<compilerSource default-value="${maven.compiler.source}">${maven.compiler.source}</compilerSource>  `. Where do you have located you source files? How does you pom file look like?

Comment: I added the full log to the post. Both vars are set to 1.8 unless I have done something stupid...

Comment: can you add details to exactly how can I reproduce it >

Comment: I created my own formatter using JDT as well https://site.trajano.net/m2e-codestyle-maven-plugin/format-mojo.html in case you want to see if it will work better for you.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with skipping my Java source files. I found out that the problem lied in the newest Eclipse version, which I used for generating my XML config file.

The maven code formatter (version 0.4) namely works only with Eclipse formatter 3.8: https://code.google.com/p/maven-java-formatter-plugin/wiki/Features

After I downloaded an older Eclipse version and generated my XML config file again, everything worked, the files were not skipped.

If you are heading the same problem, first try to run your formatter with a profile that should definitely work, e.g.: https://code.google.com/p/google-styleguide/source/browse/trunk/eclipse-java-google-style.xml
...to be sure the problem lies not in your XML config file.

I am not sure this is an answer to the above question since there is no statement how the config file has been generated...but I hope this answer will save some time somebody...

Answer (score 0):

You will need to upgrade the version of Eclipse being used by the plugin and make sure the versions in the configuration file are aligned with the versions in the project.  This configuration is working for me with Java8.

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>com.googlecode.maven-java-formatter-plugin</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-java-formatter-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>0.4</version>
  <configuration>
    <configFile>${project.basedir}/eclipse-formatter-config.xml</configFile>
    <overrideConfigCompilerVersion>true</overrideConfigCompilerVersion>
  </configuration>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.eclipse.text</groupId>
      <artifactId>org.eclipse.text</artifactId>
      <version>3.5.101</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
      <artifactId>org.eclipse.jdt.core</artifactId>
      <version>3.10.0.v20140604-1726</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <phase>format</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>format</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Note that I have a format lifecycle extension installed, so you will need to rework the `<extensions/>` block or add that lifecycle to your project:

```
<extensions>
  <extension>
    <groupId>com.xiantrimble.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-format-lifecycle</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
  </extension>
</extensions>
```

And run the formatter with this command:

```
mvn format
```